# Custom build command does not work with `cargo publish` because CMake says the path would exceed CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX

Tags: cmake, rust, vulkan, rust-cargo

My project can be built and run locally, but when running `cargo publish` I get an error:

```
PS C:\Users\jonat\Projects\vulkano_blas> cargo publish
    Updating crates.io index
   Packaging vulkano_blas v0.1.0 (C:\Users\jonat\Projects\vulkano_blas)
   Verifying vulkano_blas v0.1.0 (C:\Users\jonat\Projects\vulkano_blas)
   Compiling autocfg v1.0.0     
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0 
   Compiling maybe-uninit v2.0.0
   Compiling libc v0.2.73       
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10     
   Compiling cc v1.0.58
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.19
   Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0  
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.1 
   Compiling syn v1.0.35
   Compiling vulkano v0.19.0
   Compiling either v1.5.3
   Compiling smallvec v1.4.1
   Compiling vk-sys v0.5.2
   Compiling half v1.6.0
   Compiling fnv v1.0.7
   Compiling itertools v0.9.0
   Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.7.2
   Compiling memoffset v0.5.5      
   Compiling crossbeam-epoch v0.8.2
   Compiling shared_library v0.1.9
   Compiling cmake v0.1.44
   Compiling quote v1.0.7
   Compiling shaderc-sys v0.6.2
   Compiling crossbeam-queue v0.2.3  
   Compiling crossbeam-channel v0.4.3
   Compiling crossbeam-deque v0.7.3
   Compiling crossbeam v0.7.3
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: System installed library not found.  Falling back to build from source

error: failed to verify package tarball

Caused by:
  failed to run custom build command for `shaderc-sys v0.6.2`
```

[Middle part removed due to its size](https://hastebin.com/rusufuruhu.sql)

```
--- stderr
CMake Warning in spirv-tools/source/reduce/CMakeLists.txt:
  The object file directory

    C:/Users/jonat/Projects/vulkano_blas/target/package/vulkano_blas-0.1.0/target/debug/build/shaderc-sys-81aff4f7b9007197/out/build/spirv-tools/source/reduce/CMakeFiles/SPIRV-Tools-reduce.dir/./

  has 191 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
  characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

    remove_unreferenced_instruction_reduction_opportunity_finder.cpp.obj

  cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
  correctly.


CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER
    CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS


thread 'main' panicked at '
command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1

build script failed, must exit now', C:\Users\jonat\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.44\src\lib.rs:885:5      
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Where does the problem lie? And how could I approach fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the path is too long for CMake / Windows.

You might try to enable Long Paths support in Windows, or put your project in a shallower path.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much of a difference `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` is set to 1 and the error remains (have restarted and retried).

Comment: Not sure how I change the cmake variable `CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX`, I'm not sure putting it in a shallower path would really work (its path is already very shallow) and beside that, that seems a pretty awkward work around.

Answer (score 0):

Building in a shallower directory worked for me:

```ini
#.cargo/config.toml
[build]
# fixes CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX
target-dir = "C:/temp/crate_name"
```

While this can also be done with a compiler flag, that is not recommended because `cargo clean` etc will not work as expected.

A side note, Ive had some runtime linker errors using this method with embuild and an esp32. The solution there was to move the entire repo closer to root and keep the default target dir, its a bummer but no two ways about it.